# extract required elements from an string

Tags: python

```
>>> s = 'apple_123_banana_carrot_dog_eggs_567'
>>> '_'.join(s.split('_')[1:4])
'123_banana_carrot'
```

The expected result is `123_banana_carrot` as above code has resulted correctly.

Above code works well, but my question: is there alternative (perhaps straight, easy, and short) way of getting the same result?

That maybe without using `'_'.join`, but not limited

Comment: It is still not clear to me what you want to get as a result. Will you always have this same string as input and you want to get the same result? Will you have other strings as input as well? What about those other strings? What is the expected output for them?

Comment: @Lysandros Nikolaou How did you count so many numbers? keep on counting ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be one solution

```
s =  'apple_123_banana_carrot_dog_eggs_567'
p = s.rsplit('_',3)[0]
print(p)
```